# How to compare String to list of items in c

Tags: c, cs50

I saw another post about similar code but they only compared the string to one other string was wondering if this works / if there's a simple more beginner-friendly way I should learn. Thank you

````
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    string user_imput = get_string("Fruit or Vegetable?, ");

    if (strcmp(user_imput, "apple"|| "blueberries" || "cherries" || "bananas" ||"grapes" || "oranges" || "watermelon" ||"lemons" == 0));
    {
        printf("Fuit!, %s\n", user_imput);
    }
    else if (strcmp(user_imput, "potatoes" || "tomatoe" ||  "onions" ||  "carrot" || "bellpepper" || "lettuce" || "cucumbers" || "broccoli" == 0));
    {
        printf("Vegtable! %s\n", user_imput);
    }

    else

    {
        printf("NA");
    }

}```
````

Comment: You need to compare each string individually with seperate `strcmp` calls.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do this is to create a function which searches through an array containing your strings. You then loop through comparing each one individually. If found, we return a truthy value right away. If the loop runs its course and finds nothing, we return a falsy value afterwards.

```
int is_fruit(string food) {
    static const string fruits[] = {     
        "apple", "blueberries", "cherries" /* ... */
    };                            
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof fruits / sizeof fruits[0]); i++)
        if (strcmp(fruits[i], food) == 0)          
            return 1;
                                                                  
    return 0;                                                     
}
```

Then your `if ... else` looks something like:

```
if (is_fruit(user_input)) {
    /* ... */
} else if (is_vegetable(user_input)) {
    /* ... */
} else {
    /* ... */
}
```

A good exercise would be to complete the function above (fill out the array), and write a similar one for vegetables. An even better exercise would be to wring a more generic function that takes a string and any array of strings, and deciding if the array contains the string. Its function prototype would look like this:

```
int string_array_contains(const string array[], size_t length, const string s);
```

It would work very similarly to the function above, except you would have to pass in the length of the array, since [`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) cannot be used to determine the length of the `array` argument.

---

If functions and arrays are too advanced for you at the moment, then simply know that you must compare each string individually using `strcmp`. Writing this by hand leads to very long, hard to maintain code:

```
if (strcmp(user_input, "apple") == 0 || strcmp(user_input, "blueberries") == 0 /* ... */) {
    /* ... */
}
```